# Launching a reduced browser

Tags: android, browser, navigation

Sorry for the title, I couldn't argue something better.

Here is my question: Is it possible to launch a browser on Android and don't give the option to change page?

For instance, if I launch a browser to stackoverflow.com, i want the user to navigate on the site, but don't give the ability to go to another site.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to go is [WebView](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

A WebView has several customization points where you can add your own behavior. These are:

- Creating and setting a WebChromeClient subclass. This class is called when something that might impact a browser UI happens, for instance, progress updates and JavaScript alerts are sent here.
- Creating and setting a WebViewClient subclass. It will be called when things happen that impact the rendering of the content, eg, errors or form submissions. You can also intercept URL loading here.
- Via the WebSettings class, which contains miscellaneous configuration.
- With the addJavascriptInterface(Object, String) method. This lets you bind Java objects into the WebView so they can be controlled from the web pages JavaScript